# How do we resize images in Android?

Tags: android, image

I have been looking around and can't find a positive answer to this. For images, do we use hard-coded dp for the layout width and height or do we use wrap_content? For example, say I have an imageview with an icon as its image. If I use wrap_content, the image is too big, and there is no way to resize it (image was made using xxhdpi in mind). If I set the dp manaully then the image doesn't scale with the device if its screen is larger (or does it, I'm not sure if it still does?).

I want to know the workflow we're suppose to follow, I have read all the documentation but it's vague in terms of scaling images. I have an image for each of the various screen sizes (hdpi, mdpi, etc.).

### Questions

1. If I hardcoded the width and height, does android still use those
   images (hdpi, mdpi, etc) for different screen sizes?
2. Is hardcoding the width and height bad practice, if so, what is the
   alternative to resizing the image?
3. What if we hardcoded the size for each screen resolution? So for
   example, I would use 200dp x 200dp for tablets and 100dp x 100dp for
   phones when hardcoding the width and height of an image. Is this a
   good approach?
4. What is the best workflow to follow when working with images? Should
   I create a different size of an image for each screen resolution?
   Should I use one large image and then hardcode the size for each
   layout?

Is there a website or program in which I can provide an image and it automatically comes up with the various screen density images? For example, I upload an image and it will give me an mdpi, hdpi, hdpix, and etc images for it. I have looked around, but can only find programs that work with icons, not images.

Comment: You should better ask one question per post next time.

Comment: All the questions are related, would making 5 different questions really be better than keeping it all in one question?

Comment: Also you do realize that icons are actually images.. right?

Comment: Have you tried "scaleType" attribute?

Comment: Yeah, but programs treat them as icons. If I upload say a wallpaper, it will find the various sizes but each is an icon.

Comment: Scale type does nothing to my images. They remain the same size.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to rely on the android system to scale your images appropriately. Check out the Dev docs for various scaling methods

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I get that, but what I don't get is the original size of my images? Do I design all my images for one screen size, then appropriately scale them for different screen resolutions? I just don't understand the workflow.

Comment: Its always easier to scale down images so you basically want to include the largest necessary then scale it accordingly with the Scale type. For absolute best practices this should be done for each res level such as XXHDPI ect.