# Android Studio - ImagesViews go wild on diferent screens

Tags: android

I everybody i'm learning how to use android studio for the first time and i'm having problems with my images.

I used android studio design interface to position my imageviews on their correct positions and i also used it to resize them. The problem is that when i run it on emulator, even though i'm using the same "canvas" on the android studio design interface as the screen on the emulator, the images appear in different positions. And if i try different emulators with different screen sizes they can go even more wild and change their positions intarelly.

I made some research and most of the people say that android studio needs different images and create different drawable folders for each screen type.

I've done that and it almost fixed my problem but some of the images still change their position a bit. I suspect that my problem is that i resize the images with android design tool, but i'm not sure.

Can someone theorize why this is happening? (if it is about using the design interface to change the images width and height that is creating my problem)

What is the best way (practices, methods, tools,...) to put images without them changing their positions in different screens?

Shall i change the images sizes on photoshops for example instead of on android studio?

P.S: I know it's too much to read but i would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using anything to position the ImageViews in the activity - like constraints in a ConstraintLayout?

Comment: yes i'm using constraints

Comment: Can you add your layout xml?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/E9eheFxb

Comment: You're only constraining the ImageViews to the parent - you should also / instead constrain them to each other e.g. Top of ImageView2 constrained to Bottom of ImageView1 etc.

Comment: I'll try it. One more thing The fact i'm resizing the images like "android:layout_width="79dp"" won't create problems in different screen sizes?

Comment: You can try ScaleType. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977557/how-do-we-resize-images-in-android

Comment: ok thanks for the help i'll see if i can solve it tomorrow  with a fresh spirit of mind